# Jmeter untrusted connection- unable to record

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record a session using proxy server for JMeter 2.13.  I am getting following error. I tried getting the proxycert file into the certificate but it is still not working.  There is no way accept the certificate.

Any inputs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) the solution is as simple as clearing your browsing data.

It looks like you're using Firefox so follows steps from [How do I clear my history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox#w_how-do-i-clear-my-history) KB article.

Comment: Clearing browser didnot help.  I get the same error.  I tried in Chrome, it reocrds but I get warning. For Firefox, I edited, jmeter.properties file, to accept SSLv3 but this does not work too